# PrimeFaces tags not working with new design using jquery and other jquery libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using PrimeFaces some tags in my jsf pages .its working fine in my old design but when i promoted my application to new design in which is extensively use of jquery and other jquery liberaries like bootstrap,morris and slimscroll etc.
my header page liberaries are as below which i tried .

```
      <script src="resources/js/jQuery-2.1.3.min.js"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/morris.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.knob.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/daterangepicker.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/icheck.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/fastclick.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/dashboard2.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/app.min.js"/>
    <script src="resources/js/dashboard.js"/>     
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $ = jQuery;
    </script>
/// and in page where i use primefaces tag is below
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-latest.js"/>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"        target="head" />
   $.noConflict();  
    jQuery.noConflict();
        $ = jQuery;
     </script>

     <p:autoComplete value="#{orderBean.customerBean}"
                        id="customer"
                        completeMethod="#{orderBean.autoCompleteCustomer}"
                        var="c"
                        itemLabel="#{c.customerName}" 
                        itemValue="#{c}"
                        converter="customerc"
                        forceSelection="true"
                        required="#{orderBean.isRequired()}"
                        requiredMessage="customer:Please enter Customer!!">
            <f:facet    name="itemtip">
                <h:panelGrid  columns="2"  
                              border="1"
                              styleClass="itemTip"
                              cellspacing="1"  cellpadding="10" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText   
                            value="#{c.customerName}" 
                            style="alignment-adjust: central;" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="Customer Type" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.customerType}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Contact Person" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.contactPerson}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Email" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.customerEmail}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Phone No" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.customerPhoneNo}" />
                    <h:outputText value="GST No" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.customerGstNo}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </f:facet>
            <p:ajax event="blur" process="customer"
                    listener="#{orderBean.handleCustomerBlur}"
                    update="customer, productName, quantity, packingName, packs,orderTable, addToListButton ,addPackingButton" >
            </p:ajax> 

        </p:autoComplete>
```

but primefaces tag is not working  due new jquery files included in my design .please any one help me to overcome this situtation so that i can work with new design futhur.

Comment: howcome people do not find the duplicates or that they do not show up when creating new questions...

Comment: but this could not solve my issue so i decided to ask new question BalusC.....

Comment: Then very clearly state **why** the other post does **not** solve your problem. And what you did to circumvent what is described there

Comment: In other questions just for one page .in my case in header file i use jquery then in other page where primefaces tags are used .

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand what you mean. If in non-PF pages you use your own jquery and in PF pages you use the PF one, there should not be a problem